# Percent layout won't work

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I was googling for ways of specifying Width and Height of views in Android. 
I found

> Xamarin.Android.Support.Percent library

Link to official example: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamandroidsupportpercent

I used package manager to obtain this library and copy pasted axml code from the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <View
      android:background="#f0f0f0"
      app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
      app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
      app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
      app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%" />
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

It can't even compile, errors i get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error No
>   resource identifier found for attribute layout_widthPercent,
>   layout_heightPercent, layout_marginTopPercent,
>   layout_marginLeftPercent

Does anyone has an idea of what is wrong? 
I am pretty new to Xamarin and Android. Is there something I need to write in AndroidManifest.xml or AssemblyInfo.cs? 
Any other advice?

Comment: @azizbekian Nothing changed

Comment: @azizbekian when I rewrote the line to old value it magically started to work. Thanks for the comment